# How to purchase each item in recyclerview with in-app purchase

Tags: java, android, android-studio, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am trying to add in-app purchase for my app.The problem is that i need to purchase for each item in recyclerview.

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

//Billing
private BillingClient billingClient;
private List skuList = new ArrayList();
private String sku = "sk_peoplesio_new_connection";
SkuDetails skuDetails ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_freelancer_order);

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.freelancer_purchased_order_btn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(FreelancerOrderActivity.this,FreelancerPurchasedOrderActivity.class));
        }
    });
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.freelancer_order_list);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Long press on the item to view their request's...!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    //Billing
    skuList.add(sku);

    setupBillingClient();
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("FreelancerOrders").child(Freevalent.currentOnlineFreelancer.getPhone());

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ClientOrders> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ClientOrders>()
                    .setQuery(reference,ClientOrders.class)
                    .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ClientOrders, TextViewHolder> adapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ClientOrders, TextViewHolder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final TextViewHolder  textViewHolder, int i, @NonNull final ClientOrders requests) {

                    textViewHolder.name.setText("Do you want this order...?" + "\n\n"+"Long press to see the client's  requests's");


                    textViewHolder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(FreelancerOrderActivity.this,FreelancerParticularClientActivity.class);
                            i.putExtra("phone",requests.getPhone());
                            startActivity(i);
                            return true;
                        }
                    });

                    textViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FreelancerOrderActivity.this);
                            builder.setTitle("Do you want to buy this Connection...?")
                                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            reference.child(requests.getUnique()).removeValue()
                                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                                            //Billing
                                                            BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                                                                    .setSkuDetails(skuDetails).build();
                                                            billingClient.launchBillingFlow(FreelancerOrderActivity.this,billingFlowParams);


                                                            new CountDownTimer(180000000,1000)
                                                            {

                                                                @Override
                                                                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                                                    textViewHolder.name.setText("Seconds Remaining : " + millisUntilFinished/1000);
                                                                }

                                                                @Override
                                                                public void onFinish() {
                                                                    purchaseSingleClientInfo(requests.getPhone());
                                                                }
                                                            }.start();





                                                        }
                                                    });
                                        }
                                    }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }).show();
                        }
                    });


                }

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public TextViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.request_item_layout,parent,false);
                    TextViewHolder holder = new TextViewHolder(view);
                    return holder;
                }
            };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
}

private void purchaseSingleClientInfo(String phone)
{
    final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("FreelancerOrders").child(Freevalent.currentOnlineFreelancer.getPhone());
    final DatabaseReference clientRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ClientOrders").child(phone).child(Freevalent.currentOnlineFreelancer.getPhone());
    clientRef.child("state").setValue("t");
    reference.child(phone).child("state").setValue("t");
    Toast.makeText(FreelancerOrderActivity.this, "Click the Button below..!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

//Billing
@Override
public void onPurchasesUpdated(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
    int responseCode = billingResult.getResponseCode();
    if(responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases!=null)
    {
        for(Purchase purchase : purchases)
        {
            handlePurchase(purchase);
        }
    }
    else if(responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED)
    {

    }
    else if(responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED)
    {

    }

}

private void handlePurchase(Purchase purchase) {
    if(purchase.getSku().equals(sku))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Purchase Done...!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}

private void setupBillingClient() {

    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).enablePendingPurchases().setListener(this).build();
    billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {
            if(billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK)
            {
                //The billing client is setup successfully
                loadAllSkus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            //Try to restart the connection on the next request to Google play by calling the start Connection method.
        }
    });

}

private void loadAllSkus()
{
    if(billingClient.isReady())
    {
        SkuDetailsParams params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkusList(skuList)
                .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
                .build();

        billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params, new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSkuDetailsResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<SkuDetails> list) {
                if(billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK)
                {
                    for(Object skuDetailsObject : list )
                    {
                        skuDetails = (SkuDetails) skuDetailsObject;
                        if(skuDetails.getSku().equals(sku))
                        {

                        }
                        else if(skuDetails.getSku().equals("something_else"))
                        {
                            //do this

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

I've followed [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrHCa1BaNgg). I need to make purchase for each item and i will acknowledge with the other tutorial of same channel.

And i want to pass requests.getPhone() to purchaseSingleClientInfo Method when the purchase is done.

Answer (score 0):

An in-app product can only be purchased once, the user can't own the same product more than one, if you want it to be bought several times you have to consume it before.

It seems that you want to buy all the products on the list at once.

The in-app billing library does not offer any method to buy several products at the same time, the only way is one by one through the dialog that asks for the payment method and other options.

Comment: No i don't want to purchase all list items at once . Each item should be bought independently.Can you please help ? i don't know how to do sir.

Comment: Follow the steps on this document : https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate